# Business Logic in Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, jsp, transactions, acid

​
hi,

writing in to get some expert advice and second opinions for best practices on stored procedures.

we have reached the phase of our ERP where we are building functionality for transaction entry. having read through several forums, we've decided to encapsulate our business logic in stored procedures, mainly because:

- several rows and tables have to be updated for every transaction entered
- we need atomicity for the account updates
- we need atomicity for the transaction updates: either the whole transaction goes through - we need isolation (row locks) of the specific accounts when a transaction data is being updated in the master & transactional tables

the summarized strategy:

1. input of data for transaction in the view (jsp)
2. data validation in view (jsp & js)
3. sanitize/validate data in model
4. insert the transaction in the transaction table & get the transaction_id
5. call the specific stored proc based on the transaction type (there is one SP for each transaction type)
6. in the SP

a. start transaction
b. acquire lock on each account code that needs to be updated
c. update each ledger
d. commit if success (which automatically releases all locks at end of transaction)
e. rollback if error (which automatically releases locks at end of transaction)
f. return error/success code g. update the view with error/success

we are using InnoDB engine in MySQL 5.6.

looking for any sort of feedback that i can get from you guys... where are the danger zones, maybe something that we are not considering, something that you'd like me to consider.

thanks in advance,
ksheer